# How to display other elements on an image smoothly?

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling to put some element on an image smoothly and make them responsive, but other tags such as p, h1, a etc. ruins the alignment. I would like to know what could I do?

Source code:  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atahta/jm64uewo/)

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image: screenshot]

The problems I'm facing to are:

> Text are involving into each other
>
> Texts are overflowing out of the container

PHP:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="slider-space">
        <span class="others">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'website', true ) ); ?>">Read More</a>
        </span>
        </header>
    </article>
```

This code renders following out put:

```
        <article id="post-227" class="post-227 cafes type-cafes status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">
        <header class="slider-space">
        <span class="others">
                <img width="618" height="246" src="https://www.flynsarmy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/nivoslider/images/up.jpg" />
            <h1>Im just a h1 tag line</h1>
            
            <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            
            <a href="www.google.com">Read More</a>
        </span>
        </header>
    </article>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-space {position:relative;width: 100%; height: auto; text-align: center; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);}
.slider-space img{ width: 100%; height: auto;}
.slider-space span, .slider-space a, .slider-space h1{color: #FFF;}
```

Comment: why not use the image as a background image

Comment: Yes your suggestion was in my mind, but I'm tend to be do it later image slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a wrapper DIV for these elements and give it the following settings, which will place it above its (relatively position) container ( `. slider-space`) and center it inside that:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Here is it in your jsfiddle, the wrapper is the `.overlay` DIV:

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lvvf95c/

Comment: I've tried this settings but elements are disappeared  [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/atahta/jm64uewo/)

Comment: ah sorry, I didn't see that `.others` also contained the image - you need an additional wrapper DIV - please have a look at my changed answer  + fiddle

Comment: Yes it works now but when resize the window texts are overflowing, How coult I scale texts inside of outer div?

Comment: use media queries to reduce the font-size on smaller screens